# Can I still use handleRequest() after dumping the request?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller, request

My idea at the moment is to perform the following in my Symfony controller:

```
dump($request);

/* Some code to handle the request manually */

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Will my `handleRequest` call actually function properly (meaning, populate my `User` entity as expected), or is dumping a subtractive action that would somehow make the contents of the request no more accessible for the `handleRequest` function?

Comment: Unless you remove or alter POST parameters from the request object, you should be fine. What do you plan on doing with the request anyway ?

Comment: This is one of those answer a question with a question post.  Specifically, what happened when you tried it?